How many chips do you need to add to the batter, so that the probability of 100 cookies you bake each has at least 1 chip is more than 0.9.
You are making chocolate chip cookies. You add N chips randomly to the dough and you randomly split the dough into 100 equal cookies. How many chips should go into the dough to give a probability of at least 90% that every cookie has at least one chip?
This question is a duplicate. However, I wanted to see why my solution is incorrect.
Let $x_1,\cdots x_{100}$ denote the amount of chips in the $i$'th cookie. By stars and bars there are exactly $N+99 \choose 99$ ways the chips can be distributed among the cookies.
Again by stars and bars, there are $N-1 \choose 99$ ways to distribute the chips, assuring that each cookie has at least one. Therefore the probability that all cookies have at least one chip should be
$$\frac{N-1 \choose 99}{N+99 \choose 99}$$.
However, this is not correct. What is the mistake here? I think I am just assuming that each distribution of chips to the cookies has equal probability. Is that not true?
Thank you.

Yes, the problem is that the distributions you are counting are not equally likely. That is because the chips are physically distinct objects, even if you can't tell the difference between them, so randomly mixing will always treat them as distinguishable. Thus there are $100^N$ arrangements, and one way to count the number of successful ones is by inclusion-exclusion.

I see, so if the chips were non-distinguishable, then what have written is correct?

@Sorfosh No. The chips are physically distinct, so any way that you mix them must treat them as distinguishable. There's simply no way to get a uniformly random arrangement of non-distinguishable chips by physically shuffling some real chips about.

It's like rolling dice. The chance of rolling double-six is 1/36, even using indistinguishable dice, because the dice are distinguishable to each other even if they aren't to you.

I am confused. Consider the following procedure. I divide the dough into 100 pieces. Now I have N chips to distribute with 1/100 probability a chip falls into a particular cookie. Wouldn't any random arrangement be equally probable?

Say you have 100 chips. Now there is only 1 way to put them all in the first cookie, but $100!$ ways to put one in each cookie (you can do this in any order). So the second arrangement is vastly more likely.
